# Copying an array for sorting not working correctly in MIPS program?

Tags: arrays, mips, mars-simulator

I'm working on a sorting program that sorts an array of integers, for which I copy the array entered in by the user into a new array to be mutated. However, I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

```
.globl main

.data 

input: .asciiz "Enter the size of the array: \n"

entries: .asciiz "Enter the elements of the array, one line at a time: \n"

output: .asciiz "Original array and then sorted array: \n"

space: .asciiz " "


.text

main:

   subi $sp, $sp 32

   sw $ra, 0($sp)

   sw $t0, 4($sp) # the size of the array

   sw $t4, 8($sp) # the number 4

   sw $t1, 12($sp) # temporary

   sw $t2, 16($sp) # array original

   sw $t3, 20($sp) # specific element

   sw $s1, 24($sp) # copied array

   sw $t5, 28($sp) # number to copy

   la $a0, input

   li $v0, 4

   syscall

   # get the size

   li $v0, 5
   syscall
   move $t0, $v0

  # allocate space for the array on the heap
  li $t4, 4
  mul $t1, $t0, $t4
  li $v0, 9
  move $a0, $t1
  syscall
  move $t2, $v0

  li $s0, 0
  la $a0, entries
  li $v0, 4
  syscall

read_array:
  # read element
  li $v0, 5
  syscall
  move $t3, $v0

  # place in right address
  mul $t1, $s0, $t4
  add $t1, $t2, $t1
  sw $t3, 0($t2)

  addi $s0, $s0, 1
  blt $s0, $t0, read_array

  li $s0, 0

gnome_sort: 
  # allocate space on heap for copy
  mul $t1, $t0, $t4
  li $v0, 9
  move $a0, $t1
  syscall
  move $s1, $v0

  mul $s2, $t4, $t0
  add $s3, $s1, $s2

copy_array:
  lw $t5, 0($t2)
  sw $t5, 0($s1)

  add $t2, $t2, $t4
  add $s1, $s1, $t4

  blt $s1, $s3, copy_array

  li $s0, 0
  while_loop:
  bgt $s0, $t0, finish_sort
  beq $s0, $zero, increase_i
  sw $s4, 0($s1)
  sw $s5, -4($s1)
  bge $s4, $s5, increase_i
  j swap_elements

  increase_i:
  addi $s0, $s0, 1
  j while_loop              

  swap_elements:
  la $a0, input
  li $v0, 4
  syscall

  sw $t6, 0($s1)
  sw $t7, -4($s1)
  lw $t7, 0($s1)    
  lw $t6, -4($s1)
  subi $s0, $s0, 1

  j while_loop

  finish_sort:
  li $s0, 0

  la $a0, output
  li $v0, 4
  syscall
  j print_original

print_original:

  bge $s0, $t0, print_sorted
  lw $s6, 0($t2)

  li $v0, 1
  move $a0, $s6
  syscall

  la $a0, space
  li $v0, 4
  syscall

  addi $s0, $s0, 1
  j print_original

print_sorted:
  li $s0, 0
  loop:
  bge $s0, $t0, finish
  lw $s6, 0($s1)

  li $v0, 1
  move $a0, $s6
  syscall

  la $a0, space
  li $v0, 4
  syscall

  addi $s0, $s0, 1
  j loop
finish:
  li $v0, 10
  syscall
```

Answer (score 1):

After testing this in QTSpim, it seems that you're going out of allocated memory on the line `sw $s4, 0($s1)` 
in the `while_loop`. This is because `$s1` at that point is past the end of the second array you allocated. If you want to use that memory, you will have to `syscall` for it.
The way you copy the array using `lw` and `sw` is correct.

Comment: Syscall for what exactly? Sbrk?

Comment: Yes, but I think you just need to reset `$s1` back to point to the beginning of that array.

Comment: You just use `move` usually. The trick is to save the pointer to the beginning of the array in one register, and then copy the pointer (with `move`) to another register. This way, you always have a head pointer and a current pointer. The head pointer can always stay at the head of the array, and the current pointer can walk over the array. When you need to walk over the array again, you can`move` from the head register back to the current register. This is just like iterating over a linked list in a high level language.

Comment: The pointer is just a 32-bit number (that represents a memory address). Whenever you do a memory operation like `lw $r1 0($r2)`, you are reading the data from memory address `$r2` into register `$r1`. `$r2` holds a pointer in this case.

Comment: Is the head pointer accessible by just doing 0($s1) before the loop? Still a bit lost.

Comment: Basically, whenever you want to iterate over some portion of memory, and you want to get back to the beginning of that memory, you need to save the pointer (the address) in a register. And then use another register to do the actual iteration. That way, you don't lose the beginning of the array.

Comment: @cococunt `$s1` is 32 bit register, it contains 32 bits of information. When you use it as `li $s1, 13`, then you can *interpret* it as "s1 contains integer value 13". And when you use it as `la $s1, input`, then you can *interpret* it as "s1 contains address input". But in both cases the `s1` is still just 32 bits. You can actually in both cases use the other interpretation, i.e. treat the value `13` mentally as an memory address (leading to unaligned word read crash with `lw $0,($s1)`), or you can interpret `input` address as integer (for example `0x800001B4`). CPU sees either just 32 bits.